# Can this code be improved by returning a pointer to a struct?

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code that gets the MAC address of an interface:

```
static struct ifreq get_mac( int socket_desc, char *if_name ) {                                                                                                                                                                         
      struct ifreq if_mac;                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      memset( &if_mac, 0, sizeof( struct ifreq ) );                                                                                                                                                                                       
      strncpy( if_mac.ifr_name, if_name, IFNAMSIZ - 1 );                                                                                                                                                                                  
      ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      return if_mac;                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
}
```

My C experience is limited to what I did in college.  I roughly get pointers but I understand that returning large `struct`s by value is a bad idea because you can run out of stack space (stackoverflow!).  How can I change the above code to return a pointer to `if_mac` instead ?  It's just a bit confusing because there's a `struct` and an 'address of' operator :S.

Comment: You can allocate the structure on heap using `malloc()` and then return a pointer to it.Whether this is better w.r.t performance can only be determined by profiling both implementations.

Comment: I agree with Als' answer. And do not forget release the memory when if_mac is no longer used.

Comment: Or you can let the caller allocate one (it already has one) and pass a pointer to the function in an extra element : `void get_mac( ifreq *ptr, int socket_desc, char *if_name )`

Comment: From what I just could find, `struct ifreq` has about 32 bytes. That is not a "large `struct`".

Comment: But where does it store the name, than? Or is the name limited to 3+1 characters?

Comment: Returning pointer to struct is quite similar to returning an `int` or `float` for example.Should be easy if you spend a couple of minutes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a pointer to the expected structure in parameter:

```
static int ifreq get_mac(int socket_desc, char *if_name, struct ifreq **if_mac)
{
      if (NULL == (*ifmac = malloc(sizeof (struct ifreq))) {
          return -1;                                        
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      memset(*if_mac, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));                                                                                                                                                                                       
      strncpy((*if_mac)->ifr_name, if_name, IFNAMSIZ - 1);                                                                                                                                                                                  
      ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
}
```

If the caller has already allocated the space for the structure, the function prototype becomes:

```
static int ifreq get_mac(int socket_desc, char *if_name, struct ifreq *if_mac)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd do better to take the struct by pointer as an out-parameter, thus deferring the decision and responsibility for dynamic memory management (if any) to the caller:

```
static void get_mac( int socket_desc, char *if_name, struct ifreq *if_mac ) { 
    ...
}
```

However, given that most compilers will optimise large struct return to an out-parameter call anyway, there's not much point.  Do you know how large the struct `if_mac` is?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically allocate memory (malloc) to `if_mac`  and return the pointer Or Pass the pointer to the function itself, creating one before the function call and apply changes.

Dont return anything in second case.
That may help.